# PyCharm doesn't autocomplete Django "models" in 2018.3.2

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've created my Django project with PyCharm. When I use the `objects` attribute in my model, PyCharm doesn't recognize `objects`.

[image]

I've visited this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722859/pycharm-doesnt-autocomplete-django-model-queries-anymore-in-2016-1-2), but I haven't got the Django option in settings: "Settings/Languages & Frameworks/Django" !

Comment: Have you try `Mark Directory as -> Sources root`?

Comment: Are you using PyCharm Community Edition? Django support is only available in the Professional edition.

Comment: Ah... thank ! I'll use PyCharm Pro !

Comment: Side note: Even if you use Pycharm Pro then having django-stubs installled may fail autocomplete/suggestions .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to the current version of PyCharm (2020.1), Django support, including code completion, is only available in PyCharm Professional - see the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html#top). Django is not supported by PyCharm Community Edition.