# How to have PyCharm suggest code completion for Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-contrib

I have the following code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ModelTests(TestCase)
    def test_newUserEmailNormalized(self):
        email = "test@TEST.COM"
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email, 'test123')
```

I want PyCharm to suggest autocompletion on the last line when I write `get_user_model().` but it only suggests `main, not, par`.

And when I write `get_user_model().objects.` I want it to suggest auto-completion options including `create_user` but it doesn't suggest anything.

How do I enable PyCharm to help me with autocompletion here?  These are my AutoCompletion settings:

[image: PyCharm Code Completion Settings]

Comment: I think this is the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038129/pycharm-doesnt-autocomplete-django-models-in-2018-3-2. Essentially, Django support exists only in PyCharm Pro.

Comment: I see.  Thank you @dspencer

Answer (score 0):

It appears Django support exists only in PyCharm Professional edition, not in PyCharm Community Edition.

Thanks to @dspencer in the comments.